# Dynamic programming in Python

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have been trying for a couple of days to implement a simple program from a Matlab code to Python. I am using numpy but if there is a better way I am open to it.

This is my Matlab code:

```
x=[1,1,1,9];
A=zeros(length(x),length(x));
for i=length(x):-1:1
    for j=length(x):-1:i
        if i==length(x)
            A(i,j)=x(i);
        else
            if j>i
                A(i,j)=A(i+1,j)+(j-i);
            elseif j==i
                A(i,j)=x(i)+min(A(j+1,j+1:end));
            end
        end
    end
end
y=min(A(1,:));
```

It creates this matrix:

```
 12    12    13    15
 0    11    11    12
 0     0    10    10
 0     0     0     9
```

and the final result is 12 (the minimum from the first row).
This is what I have done in Python so far:

```
import numpy as np

items = np.array([1,1,1,9])
sizeLimit = len(items)
P = np.zeros((len(items),len(items)))

for i in range(0, sizeLimit):
  for j in range(i, sizeLimit):
    if i == sizeLimit-1:
        P[i,j] = items[i]
    else:
        if j > i:
            P[i,j] = P[i+1,j] + [j-i]
        elif j == i:
            P[i,j] = items[i] + P[0, 0:].min()
print P
```

It seems it gets stuck somewhere and does not iterate.

I would be grateful to any help.

Comment: Is hard to understand your code. Can you explain what is this intended to do? I mean, what pattern you want to get in the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to replicate your Matlab result with:

```
import numpy as np

items = np.array([1,1,1,9])
sizeLimit = len(items)
P = np.zeros((len(items),len(items)))

for i in range(sizeLimit-1, -1, -1):
  for j in range(sizeLimit-1, i-1, -1):
    if i == sizeLimit-1:
        P[i,j] = items[i]
    else:
        if j > i:
            P[i,j] = P[i+1,j] + [j-i]
        elif j == i:
            P[i,j] = items[i] + P[j+1, (j+1):].min()
```

Giving me

```
>>> print P
[[ 12.  12.  13.  15.]
 [  0.  11.  11.  12.]
 [  0.   0.  10.  10.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   9.]]
```

The key point is to translate things like:

```
octave:1> 4:-1:1
ans =

   4   3   2   1
```

into

```
>>> sizeLimit = 4
>>> range(sizeLimit-1, -1, -1)
[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

In your original Python code things are reversed. `range` also excludes the end-point, unlike the Matlab function. You also need to be careful to account for the fact that unlike Matlab, Python has 0-based indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly. I was aware of 0-based indexing and tried many combinations last two days but couldn't make it work. I knew I was close :). Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Have been through the same kinds of issues in the past many times.